# Custom Maths Formula Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, input

As i choose value from the Marks Allocation dropdown, it will appear in weightage(total) column and each weightage column the value taken from each marks column [the image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLjUR.png) and all the five column values are equally total up based on the weightage(total) value but the issue is the value is not equally total up as per weightage(total).The maths formula is (each marks column / total * marks allocation). Please help me to correct my coding.

Marks Allocation field:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label>Marks Allocation (%):</label>
<select name="percentage" id="percentage" onchange="updateVall()" class="form-control" oninput="this.className = ''">
<?php 
$sql = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM continous_assess"); 
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{ ?>
              
    <option value="<?php echo $row['percentage']; ?>"><?php echo $row['percentage']; ?></option>
<?php 
}
?>
</select>
 
</div>
```

Marks field code with java script:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Marks</label>
        <input type="number" id="m1" oninput="testing1()" class="prc"/>
        <input type="number" id="m2" oninput="testing2()" class="prc"/>
        <input type="number" id="m3" oninput="testing3()" class="prc"/>
        <input type="number" id="m4" oninput="testing4()" class="prc"/>
    <input type="number" id="m5" oninput="testing5()" class="prc"/>
        <label>Total</label>
        <output id="result" name="result"></output>
    </div>
</fieldset> 

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.form-group').on('input','.prc',function(){
        var totalSum = 0;
        $('.form-group .prc').each(function(){
            var inputVal = $(this).val();
            if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
                totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
            }
    });
        $('#result').val(totalSum);
    });
</script>
```

weightage column code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Weightage</label>
    <input type="number" id="w1" name="w1" class="prc1"/>
     <input type="number" id="w2" name="w2" class="prc1"/>
     <input type="number" id="w3" name="w3" class="prc1"/>
     <input type="number" id="w4" name="w4" class="prc1"/>
     <input type="number" id="w5" name="w5" class="prc1"/>
      <label>Total</label>
       <input type="text" name="exampleInput" id="exampleInput" class="prc1"/>
  </div>
```

Javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testing1() {
  //alert("rubine_m1");
  var percentageVal = document.getElementById("percentage").value;
  var ResultVal = document.getElementById("result").value;
  var marksVal = document.getElementById("m1").value;
  var w1Resval = marksVal / ResultVal * percentageVal;
  document.getElementById("w1").value = w1Resval;
}
function testing2() {
  //alert("rubine_m2");
  var percentageVal = document.getElementById("percentage").value;
  var ResultVal = document.getElementById("result").value;
  var marksVal = document.getElementById("m2").value;
  var w2Resval = marksVal / ResultVal * percentageVal;
  document.getElementById("w2").value = w2Resval;
}
function testing3() {
  //alert("rubine_m3");
  var percentageVal = document.getElementById("percentage").value;
  var ResultVal = document.getElementById("result").value;
  var marksVal = document.getElementById("m3").value;
  var w3Resval = marksVal / ResultVal * percentageVal;
  document.getElementById("w3").value = w3Resval;
}
function testing4() {
  //alert("rubine_m4");
  var percentageVal = document.getElementById("percentage").value;
  var ResultVal = document.getElementById("result").value;
  var marksVal = document.getElementById("m4").value;
  var w4Resval = marksVal / ResultVal * percentageVal;
  document.getElementById("w4").value = w4Resval;
}
function testing5() {
  //alert("rubine_m4");
  var percentageVal = document.getElementById("percentage").value;
  var ResultVal = document.getElementById("result").value;
  var marksVal = document.getElementById("m5").value;
  var w5Resval = marksVal / ResultVal * percentageVal;
  document.getElementById("w5").value = w5Resval;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? As your formula looks pretty simple, it should not be too hard to spot the problem

Comment: why repeat the same `document.getElementById` for all function?

Comment: So, do i need to remove the document.getElementById?Kindly assist me as im beginner to PHP,tq.